# How to remap stripped text position to pdf document position

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I use pdfbox's `PDFTextStripper` to extract plain texts from two PDF files which are then compared using some NLP algorithm. The algorithm returns postions of common passages of the plain texts.

What I want to do is highlight the common passages in the PDF. The problem is that I only have the position in the plain text but not the corresponding position in the PDF. Using `PDFTextStripper` this mapping is lost.

Are there any solutions/common approaches to preserve the mapping from plain text position to PDF document position while stripping text from PDFs? I would also accept to use a different PDF library if it supports this but I have to use Java.

Comment: Essentially you will have to override the `writePage` method which from the collected `TextPosition` objects extracts the texts in a hopefully meaningful order and writes it to the output. Your override would additionally write the required positioning information, either into the same output or a secondary output stream.

Comment: Is this the only way? I wonder how the search function in all those available PDF readers are implemented. Because they do mark all occurences of the search term, right?

Comment: *Is this the only way?* — No. But the easiest given what you have already done. *I wonder how the search function in all those available PDF readers are implemented...* — if you implement a text search framework for a PDF viewer, you obviously start by keeping the positioning information. If on the other hand you implement a text search framework for a PDF library without UI component, you don't necessarily keep positioning information. And its easy to add after all.